# I want to parse a string of values and divide the output from array values by position. Why are my odd array elements not displaying?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

Why is the else statement not giving the values of sub[1], sub[3], sub[5], etc (odd array positions)?

What am I doing wrong? I thought that `i % 2 == 0` would give me the even array positions? Therefore, the else statement should give me the odd, correct?

```
public class PolyValues {

    public PolyValues() {
        String value = "5 6 8 9 1 9";

        String sub[] = value.split(" ");
        
        double coeff = 0;
        int exp = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < sub[i].length(); i++) {
            if (sub[i].isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("No input");
            }
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                try {
                    coeff = Double.parseDouble(sub[i]);
                    System.out.println(coeff);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Fix This");
                }


            } else {
                try {
                    exp = Integer.parseInt(sub[i]);
                    System.out.println(exp);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Fix This");
                }

            }

        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Polyvalues p1 = new Polyvalues();
    }
} //end of class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the length of the strings from `sub` array and not the length of that array.
Change in the for:

```
i<sub[i].length()
```

to

```
i<sub.length
```